# How to send Filebeat, Meticbeat and Packetbeat data to Fluentd daemonset deployed on 3 node Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: filebeat, fluentd, metricbeat, packetbeat

I have a 3 nodes Kubernetes cluster, on which I have fluentd deployed as damonset. This fluentd is tailing all the container logs on Kubernetes cluster and sending it to Elasticsearch deployed on the same Kubernetes cluster. I have an external Linux server which has **Filebeat**, **Metricbeat** and **Packetbeat** and I want to sends its beats data to the Fluentd running on my Kubernetes cluster, so that the beats data could be stored in the Elasticsearch. How to do that? Fluentd has elasticbeats plugin. But I am not sure how to expose the fluentd outside the kubernetes cluster (probably it would need some service), so that it can accept the beats data from the Linux server.

Comment: were you able to find the solution? can you share your findings please